# Angular 5 não escuta alterações nos arquivos

Tags: angular

estou tendo problemas com o angular 5. Ao alterar o html de um component não está recompilando o código, eu tenho que parar e reiniciar o compilador para aparecer minha alteração.
Estou usando o comando ng build --watch, aceito sugestões. Eu só preciso de uma forma de desenvolver sem ter que ficar reiniciando o compilador para ver uma alteração.
Minhas configurações são:

ubuntu 16.04 lts
Node: 9.8.0
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Angular: 5.2.9
npm 5.8.0

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: ja tentou o ng serve?

Comment: Opa, já tentei sim Eduardo. Mas no ng serve ele só consegue monitorar alterações no módulo principal.
Esse problema eu estou tendo com o template do adminlte construído usando angular. Talvez tenha algumas coisa errada nele.
Depois vou pesquisar com calma e fazer mais testes.
Obrigado